# Jenkins: Automatic version checking of Maven-Release using Unit-Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, jenkins, release

I'm trying to configure a Jenkins-Job for releasing a Java-Project with the Maven-Release-Plugin.
I want to ensure that the Major-Version, which I use to mark a Release as incompatible with an earlier Major-Version, changes if the current Release is incompatible with the previous one.

An example:

> The last release was **version 1.9.5** which contained a class named
>   **Foo**.
>   In the **current release** this class has been removed.
>   The user specifies as current release version **1.9.6** and starts the
>   Jenkins-Job.
>
> The Release should tell the user that the current major version is expected to be **2** not **1** since the API has become incompatible.

I thought of using the Unit-Tests of the previous release to test the code of the current release. If some API has become incompatible the Unit-Tests of the previous release should fail during compilation or test (assumed that there is an Unit-Test for that code).

My approach would require to keep tests in a separate project and check two versions out of my VCS.

Do you know about any Jenkins-Plugin which might help for doing so or do you have any other idea on how to check if the API has become incompatible between two major versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't have any understanding of your API so couldn't suggest any related to testing the compatibility of your API.

On the Jenkins/Maven front, I would suggest you run the actual release build as a downstream job of your tests' job by using the a post build actions option called "Trigger parameterized build on other projects"

by using this function, you can trigger the downstream job with different parameter according to the result of this job. I.e. if the entire test suite passed, trigger a minor release build and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any point of using Jenkins or the release plugin for this - how many times are you going to make a major release?

Your idea to separate the unit tests into a different project is a good one. Just run the previous release's tests against the -SNAPSHOT version you're proposing to release. If they pass, then fine. Otherwise, bump the major version number.

Comment: I'm thinking of the following steps to perform a release:  
- Checkout a fresh copy of the VCS  
- Build current code & run Unit-Tests  
- Checkout Unit-Tests of previous release  
- Run Previous Unit-Tests  
- Tag VCS with correct version  
- Start release & update current version to next snapshot version  
  
Wouldn't this be easier if we have a single Job/Tool which we only give the current and the next release version?

Comment: Yeah it would be easier to do this with a tool, I guess. Maybe you could use the http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-next-releases-mojo.html combined with the old version's unit tests?